# What is happening to my \+ in string#gsub?

Tags: ruby, regex

In a Ruby script, I'm using `string#gsub` to generate a string that is used as a regex. This regex has to match against a `+` character, so I'm using `\+` to escape it.

This example code isolates my source of confusion. In this code, the regex I want to create is `/a\+b/`. However, when I use `#gsub`, the regex that is returned is `/ab/`.

```
string = 'a\+b'
expected = Regexp.new(string)
actual = Regexp.new('x'.gsub('x', string))

# expected returns /a\+b/
# actual returns /ab/
```

I couldn't find anything in the Ruby documentation about `#gsub` and `+` characters. Can anybody help me understand what is happening to produce this result?

For now, to make my code work, I'm matching against `\x2B`, the ANSI hex code for the `+` character. Is there a way to achieve this that isn't so obfuscated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, this was tested in Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0.

Comment: Interestingly, if you use double quotes on string (`string = "a\+b"`) then both `expected` and `actual` are `/a+b/`. I can't find anything in the `gsub` documentation that says anything about meaning associated with `\+` but it is obviously trying to interpret it as something as they do allow a handful of backslashed special sequences. I know this is a non-answer, which is why I only made it a comment. :)

Comment: [`Regexp.new(Regexp.quote(string))`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-quote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s ignore the `Regexp.new` here, as it’s not really relevant—only the `gsub` itself is.

Your `\+` is being interpreted as a back-reference by `gsub`. From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form `\\d`, where `d` is a group number, or `\\k<n>`, where `n` is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement the special match variables, such as `$&`, will not refer to the current match.

While it’s not very clear (since the docs say “group *number*”), the `\+` is substituted for the global variable `$+`*; from [Ruby Quickref](http://zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html):

> `$+`: Depends on `$~`. The highest group matched by the last successful match.

We can prove this by capturing something:

```
'x'.gsub(/(x)/, 'a\+b')  #=> "axb"
```

Which shows that the `\+` is being replaced with the capture from the regex. Since you have no captures in your pattern (as it is a string), the back-reference is replaced with empty string, and you get `"ab"` as the result of the `gsub`.

Using `"a\+b"` works as it’s not actually a `\+` in there:

```
"a\+b".bytes  #=> [97, 43, 98]
'a\+b'.bytes  #=> [97, 92, 43, 98]
```

<sub>* Kind of, it’s semantically equivalent, but the match global variables themselves aren’t actually set until *after* the `gsub` finishes replacing—however the back-references are, of course, set before replacement occurs.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and solution!

Answer (score 1):

Inside a replacement string `\+` is used to refer to the value of the last capturing group (so if the regex includes, for example, 3 capturing groups `\+` is the same as `\3`). If you use the block form of `gsub` instead, these substitutions will not be performed:

```
string = 'a\+b'
actual = Regexp.new( 'x'.gsub('x') { string } )
# actual is now /a\+b/
```

Comment: +1 for providing a sound workaround (and beating me to it—long answers take a long time to write).

Answer (score 0):

The `union` method of Regexp is often used to create a regular expression from a combination of strings (and/or Regexps). Since it escapes these strings it is useful here too:

```
re = Regexp.union("a+b") # => /a\+b/
```

Answer (score -1):

`Regexp.new` will automatically handle `+`.

Try this:

```
string = 'a+b'
expected = Regexp.new(string)
actual = Regexp.new('x'.gsub('x', string))
```

Let me know if you meant something else

Another interpretation of your question led me to this:

```
string = 'a\\\+b'
expected = Regexp.new(string)
actual = Regexp.new('x'.gsub('x', string))
```

Comment: That’s not what OP meant – he wants to *match* a `+`.

Comment: Ya.. That's what came to my mind.. I think the second block of code will help